# Using code snippet in Exclusion Script Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, triggered-send, exclusion-script

I'm trying to create an exclusion script based on the output of a Code snippet which looks like:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server"> 
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var AttributesJsonJs = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(Variable.GetValue("@AttributesJsonDE"));

if(AttributesJsonJs){
 Variable.SetValue("@sendEmail",AttributesJsonDE.sendEmail);
 
} else {
 Variable.SetValue("@sendEmail","");

}
</script>

%%[ VAR @canSendEmail IF @sendEmail == "true" THEN SET @canSendEmail = "canSendEmail" ELSE SET @canSendEmail = "dontSendEmail" ENDIF ]%%

%%=v(@canSendEmail)=%%
```

My exclusion script looks like:

```
TreatAsContent(ContentArea(127290))=="dontSendEmail"
```

When I make a call to send the triggered send I can see the queue being filled, however nothing is being send, even if the output doesn't match the exclusion script. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

---

**Update DE Record** This is the record information for the column Attributes

{"sendEmail":"true","orderHasBeenFulfilled":"true","POS_StoreCashier":"Testverkoper"}

---

I've also tried the following:

```
%%[
var @str, @var, @sendEmail

/* Set the value to check */ 
SET @var = false

/* Set the string to check */ 
Set @str = AttributeValue(sendEmail)

/* Does it match */ 
if IndexOf(@str,@var) > 0 then 
    Set @sendEmail = "dontSendReceipt" 
else 
    Set @sendEmail = "sendReceipt" 
endif 
]%%

%%=v(@sendEmail)=%%
```

When testing the email in preview and test the correct value is being populated. My exclusion script looks now like this:

```
TreatAsContent(ContentBlockbyID('127567')) == dontSendReceipt
```

But still no luck..

Comment: If you remove the script from your send definition and add it to your email body, what does it show?

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs, it shows canSendEmail, which is correct

Comment: And if you capture the RequestID from your Triggered Send API call and retrieve the delivery details using the `/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{{TSDKey}}/deliveryRecords/{{RequestID}}` REST route what do you get?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, It says it's being queued. When I check the email that is being generated the code gives me the output that I need to be able to send the email, however nothing is happening

Comment: If it doesn't get sent -- the deliveryRecord result should show something once it gets past "queued".

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, the response I get back after a new submission for both outcomes is: 
{
    "id": "........",
    "messageId": "....",
    "status": "Queued"
}

Strange thing is, is that in the email the value get's populated like it should, but the exclusion script doesn't seem to get it.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the results stored in the TSD data extension?

Comment: Done Adam, this is the column that hosts the data for this script

Comment: Stupid question, but have you verified the send is not paused? If it is queueing, that means it is not necessarily erroring. It also means those are not being excluded though if its queued. That is the part I would investigate more so than the exclusion script.

Comment: @Gortonington, thanks for the thoughts, but yes it’s active. So what happens is, I see the queue being filled and after that it’s empty again, but no emails has been send or has been errored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple different solutions, I've decided to go for the RaiseError function. The exclusion will not happen too many times, so this should be sufficient enough.